# can i use fuzzy wuzzy in columns of dataframe for performing operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to DataFrame and python please help me in this, I have a dataframe with looks like:

```
index col1 col2 col3
0      A1   B1   C1
1      A1   B1   C2
2      A2   B1   C3
3      A3   B2   C4
4      A2   B1   C5
5      A4   B3   C6
6      A1   B1   C7
```

and i want to add more columns in this dataframe after few operations, which should look like

```
index col1 col2 col3  count
0      A1   B1   C1     1    
1      A1   B1   C2     2
2      A2   B1   D3     1
3      A3   B2   C4     1
4      A2   B1   D5     2 
5      A4   B3   D6     1
6      A1   B1   C1     3
```

The values of this count column increases like a counter only when col1 & col2 & (values of col3 matches more than or equal to 50%) if these 3 conditions are true only then the counter should increase.
**Do i have to use FuzzyWuzzy?**

like:

```
    col1        col2       col3             count
0    A1          B1         C1                1
1    A1          B1         C                 2
   (Matches)    (Matches)  (Matches 50%)
```

Comment: Is your question if you can use fuzzywuzzy or do you have to? Also, what does "col1 & col2 & (values of col3 matches more than or equal to 50%)" mean?

Comment: do i have to use fuzzywuzzy for this?

Comment: earlier i was using                                                       
db_data_df['count']= db_data_df.groupby(['col1','col2']).cumcount()+1 , but i want to inc counter column when col2 values matches 50% or more